# Flutter Picking Wrong Keystore path and giving error key.jks not found

Tags: dart, flutter

I followed all the steps on the Flutter official site and thought I'd done everything correctly but it is failing to locate the keystore file when I build it.

This is the error message I get showing it taking wrong path instead of 
`D:\flutterapps\testapp\key.jks`:

```
PS D:\flutterapps\testapp> flutter build apk
Initializing gradle...                                       1.3s
Resolving dependencies...                                    4.3s
Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file 'D:\flutterapps\testapp\android\app\ D: lutterappspublishkey.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                        5.3s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
PS D:\flutterapps\testapp>
```

Comment: Which steps are you referring to from the official site? What is your directory structure?

Comment: It seems that it’s serching the .jks file inside the app folder and not the parent. Tey put it on ./android/app. Btw how did you set up the signin keystore? With AS, by hand in gradle file, or what?

Comment: I set signing by this          keytool -genkey -v -keystore D:\flutterapps\testapp\key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key in terminal and it gave succsesful mesaage and created key.jks file also in that path

Comment: It considering its path as key.properties file path instead key.jks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

modified key.properties file with

```
storePassword=123456
keyPassword=123456
keyAlias=key
storeFile=key.jks
```

instead of this

```
storePassword=123456
keyPassword=123456
keyAlias=key
storeFile=D:\flutterapps\testapp\key.jks
```

and also moved key.jks to 
D:\flutterapps\testapp\android\app\key.jks

as this path shown in error inside terminal

Thanks all.

Comment: saved my day. Thank you.

Comment: It's not the cause of the problem. The real cause is in windows's backslashes. The keytool thinks those are escape characters and just ignores them. You could whether do this D:\\flutterapps\\testapp\\key.jks or this D:/flutterapps/testapp/key.jks to avoid the problem.

Comment: If you are moving your key inside your app (not recommended), don't forget to add a line `key.jks` to your .gitignore file because this file should not be uploaded to any public repository. Also you need \\ instead of \ as mentioned above.

Comment: With a second backslash per directory is enough. You don't need to move any key file.

Comment: To emphasize the points above: MOVING YOUR .JKS INTO YOUR ANDROID DIRECTORY IS MERELY A *"WORKAROUND"*!  It is *NOT* "best practice"!  The real problem was the backslashes.  You have two choices; either will work: A) `D:\\flutterapps\\testapp\\key.jks` or B) `D:/flutterapps/testapp/key.jks`

Answer (score 54):

On Windows you have to use 2 backslashes to indicate the path separation.
In your `key.properties`, you should have something like this:

```
storeFile=D:\\flutterapps\\testapp\\key.jks
```

You don't need to copy your `key.jks` file to your flutter project.

Comment: Working with forward slashes in windows.

Comment: This should be actually the right and marked answer.

Answer (score 5):

it's wherever call it from in your `build.gradle`.   insert this:

```
signingConfigs {
release {
    keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
    keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
    storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
    storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
  }
}
```

and call this in above your android{}:

```
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
```

and that key.properties file (which should be in your root android folder) should have this:

```
storePassword=12345
keyPassword=12345
keyAlias=key
storeFile=/Users/me/somekey.jks
```

Comment: Sorry I did mentioned that I already followed those three steps as per https://flutter.io/docs/deployment/android

Comment: it giving this weird error path Keystore file 'D:\flutterapps\publish\android\app\D: lutterappspublishkey.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.

Comment: what did you set as the storeFile?

Comment: my key store file name is key.jks but it taking something  as  Keystore file 'D:\flutterapps\testapp\android\app\ (less than sign) D: lutterappspublishkey.jks (greater than sign)' not found for signing config 'release'.

Comment: you sure you're calling in the key.properties file?

Answer (score 2):

In build.gradle

Replace

```
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
```

to

```
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('app/key.properties')
```

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue with my Flutter app and here's how I solved it on my Mac.

1. Ensure that your `key.properties` file is located inside the android directory, so the path should be `android/key.properties`.
2. Your key.properties file should have the following structure:

   ```
   storePassword=Yourpasswordgoeshere 
   keyPassword=Yourpasswordgoeshere
   keyAlias=key
   storeFile=/Users/yourUsername/Apps/yourappname/android/app/upload-keystore.jks
   ```
3. If you're unsure what your keyAlias key is, open your terminal and run this command `keytool -list -v -keystore /path/to/your/keystore` , replacing /path/to/your/keystore with the actual keystore path which is provided when you  run the keytool -genkey.. command. To find your keyAlias, search for
   `-alias`.

Alternatively, if you used Android Studio to generate your keystore, go to Build>Generate Signed Bundle/APK, select APK and the key store path, password and alias can be found there.

4. Open your build.gradle file located at `android>app>build.gradle`. Make sure you have added the following code above the `android` block and below
   `apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle":`

   ```
   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }
    android {..............// IGNORE THIS LINE
   ```
5. Within the defaultConfig block, check that you have also added the following code:

   ```
   signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
    buildTypes {
       release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
    }
   ```

The minifyEnabled and proguardFiles keys are used for code shrinking and obfuscation and are optional.

6. Run `flutter clean && flutter pub get`
7. Run `flutter build appbundle`. If the build process completes successfully,  you will see  `✓ Built build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab`. This path indicates where the app bundle is stored within your Flutter project.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, for me... I forgot to change my `signingConfig` to `singingConfigs.release` in my `build.gradle` file.

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
           //CHANGE THIS TO RELEASE
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, I ended up having quotes around my path.

In key.properties, change

`storeFile="D:\\mypath\\tokeystore\\key.jks"`

to

`storeFile=D:\\mypath\\tokeystore\\key.jks`