# Flutter : build app bundle failure : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, dart, deployment

I have create an App by flutter and finished it ,I want to deploy it as I read in flutter docs.
I get this error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file 'D:\flutter_project\jiyanUquraan\android\app\Users\Kato\key.jks>' not found for signing config 'release'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

My key.jks in c:/Users/Kato folder

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53973333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your key.properties file as showen below,

```
storePassword=123456
keyPassword=123456
keyAlias=key
storeFile=c:/Users/Kato/key.jks
```